# Probability of summed independent variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Assume $Z_1, Z_2, Z_3$ are independent exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda >0$ and $J$ denotes a bernoulli random variable with parameter $\theta \in [0,1]$.

$$ X = (1-\theta)Z_1 + JZ_3,$$
$$ Y = (1-\theta)Z_2 + JZ_3,$$

I'm trying to evaluate $\mathbb{P}(X > x, Y > y)$.

**My question:** what is the best approach for splitting up the sums like these?

I assume that we can always split the probabilities in the following way:

$$\begin{array}{ll}\mathbb{P}(X > x, Y > y) &= \mathbb{P}((1-\theta)Z_1 + JZ_3 > x, (1-\theta)Z_2 + JZ_3 > y) \\
&= \mathbb{P}(\min\{(1-\theta)Z_1, JZ_3\} > x, \min\{ (1-\theta)Z_2, JZ_3\} > y) ~+ \\
&~~~~ \mathbb{P}(\min\{(1-\theta)Z_1, JZ_3 \}> x, \max\{(1-\theta)Z_2, JZ_3\} > y) +~\\
&~~~~ \mathbb{P}(\max\{(1-\theta)Z_1, JZ_3 \}> x, \min\{(1-\theta)Z_2, JZ_3\} > y) +~\\
&~~~~ \mathbb{P}(\max\{(1-\theta)Z_1, JZ_3 \}> x, \max\{(1-\theta)Z_2, JZ_3\} > y)~\\
\end{array}$$
And from here proceed dissecting the $\min$'s and $\max$'s. In this particular case, it seems possible to write, i.e., $\mathbb{P}(\min\{(1-\theta)Z_1, JZ_3 \}> x)$ as $$\mathbb{P}((1-\theta)Z_1 > x, JZ_3 > x) = \mathbb{P}(Z_1 > \frac{x}{1-\theta}, JZ_3 > x),$$ however, what can $\mathbb{P}(\max\{(1-\theta)Z_1, JZ_3 \}> x)$ be reduced to? In this case it feels like a cleaner solution should exist, or if I'm missing something.

**EDIT:**

I will add that the solution I'm trying to arrive to is:

$$ P(X>y, Y>y) =\text{exp}\{{-\lambda \max\{x, y\}}\} + \frac{1-\theta}{1 + \theta}\text{exp}\left\{\frac{-\lambda}{1-\theta}(x+y)\right\}\left( 1 - \text{exp}\left\{\lambda \frac{1+\theta}{1-\theta}\min\{x,y\}\right\}\right)  $$

Would he grateful for any hints or tricks!

Comment: I assume that $J$ is independent of the others.  I think the best way to solve this is to condition on $J=0$ and $J=1$ via the law of total probability $$P[A] = P[A|J=0]P[J=0]+P[A|J=1]P[J=1]$$

Comment: @Michael thanks! It seems that $P[A|J=0]P[J=0]$ results in $exp\{\frac{-\lambda}{1-\theta}(x+y)\}(1-\theta)$, if we assume $P[J=0]=1-\theta$. However, it's still not clear in how to deal with the sums $(1-\theta)Z_{i}+Z_3$ to arrive to the remaining part of the solution. 

Since $Z_i$ are independent with the same parameter $\lambda >0$, is it correct assuming that $P((1-\theta)Z_i + Z_3 > x) = P((2-\theta)Z > x)$, where $Z = Z_i$, $i = 1,2,3$? Though this too doesn't get me anywhere (and does seem to simplify the answer too much, suggesting we lose some information by such assumption).

Comment: @Michael Another idea is to condition again on $Z_3$, as in $P((1-\theta)Z_1 + Z_3 > x, (1-\theta)Z_2 + Z_3 > y | Z_3 > z)$ $=$ $P((1-\theta)Z_1 > x - z, (1-\theta)Z_2 > y - z)P(Z_3 > z)$, however, I still can't find a way to the correct solution from here.

Comment: When you condition, you want to condition on convenient things.  The event $\{Z_3>z\}$ is not convenient since it does not lead to a simple computation (actually your work is incorrect after conditioning on $\{Z_3>z\}$).  You want to condition on $\{Z_3=z\}$ and use $$P[B] = \int_{z=-\infty}^{\infty}P[B|Z_3=z]f_{Z_3}(z)dz$$

Comment: @Michael Oh, that makes more sense, thank you for the hint!  Further, since $Z_i$ are exponential and are defined for positive values, is it correct to proceed in the following manner (I'll skip some notation to keep it short): $P[B]=\int_{0}^{\infty} P(Z_1 > \frac{\max(x-z,0)}{1-\theta}, ...|Z_3=z)f_{z_3}(z)dz $ which would split the integral in three parts: $\int_{0}^{\min(x,y)}(...) + \int_{\min(x,y)}^{\max(x,y)}(...) + \int_{max(x,y)}^{\infty}f_{z_3}(z)dz$?